GIT : how do i duplicate an entire branch that includes submodules, as a separate "backup branch"
So I have a git repo with a few branches (each branch has quite a few submodules) - now what id like to do is lets for the sake of argument say that the branch i have is called "m_branch1"  - it has quite a few submodules in it.   what id like to do is Fully duplicate "m_branch1" to a new branch lets call it "m_branch2" including all the submodules as they are in their existing state in "m_branch1".
like if was just a plain directory i could do:
cp -R m_branch1  m_branch2
this is exactly what i want but need to preserve the submodules in the 'm_branch1' git branch. I just want an entire copy exactly as it is but just as a new branch m_branch2
i used to be pretty savy but forgot an want to make sure i dont mess this up as its been a few years and i dont recall how to do this when submodules are involved.

Why not make a branch out of your current branch? git checkout m_branch1, then git checkout -b m_branch2. This will create a new branch out of m_branch1 and switch to it. This is what branching is for.

Or just git branch saved_branch branch_to_save.

Huh... i just thought there was a bunch of other steps/switches i needed to use when branching stuff with submodules (recursive) and making a duplicate in the remote origin.... so you are saying its is  just like creating a normal branch (no extra steps) - thats easy.  thought there was extra steps or special switches to preserve the submodules or something - sorry its been a while since i worked with submodules - thought it was a bit more complex than that...  lol  (how embarrassing).    PS.  I dont need to dup all the commit history as this new branch will eventually be pushed to master.

Submodules are not properties of branches, they're content of commits. There're no different kinds of branches in regard to submodules, a branch is just a branch — a name and a pointer to a commit.
